# How to fix elementor slider next and prev button out of slider box

Tags: html, css, wordpress, slider, elementor

This is the page link - https://vi6bfutoz4.onrocket.site/join/ I'm working on. Design is built by using elementor.

This is how it is looking right now.
[image]

But I need "Prev and Next" something similar like this below image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the css files.

The buttons have classes. These are **"ha-slider-prev"** and **"ha-slider-next"**

Make their position absolute and the parent div's position relative.

**/wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-22.css**

```
.ha-slider-prev, .ha-slider-next {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
top: inherit!important;
background: #152f55;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.ha-slider-prev {
left: 10px;
}

.ha-slider-next {
left: 180px; 
right: inherit!important;
}

.elementor-container.elementor-column-gap-default {
position: relative;
}

.elementor-widget, 
.ha-slider-widget-wrapper .ha-slider-container, 
.swiper-container, .elementor-widget {
 position: inherit!important;
}
```

If not working, try removing these:
**/wp-content/uploads/happyaddons/css/ha-22.css**

```
.ha-slider-next {
 right: 0;
 }
```

**/wp-content/uploads/happyaddons/css/ha-22.css**

```
 .ha-slider-widget-wrapper .ha-slider-container {
  position: relative;
  }
```

**/wp-content/plugins/happy-elementor-addons-pro/assets/vendor/swiper/css/swiper-bundle.css**

```
 .swiper-container {
 position: relative;
 }
```

**/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/css/frontend-lite.min.css**

```
 .elementor-widget{
 position: relative;
 }
```